# After updating application locale of an android app, toast message is showing in previous language

Tags: java, android, kotlin, locale, mobile-application

After setting application locale of an android app, toast message is showing in previous language

Resource string (R.string.somevalue) returns previous language value.

For example, i am in a english language now, and i am changing into arabic now, but toast message is showing in english

Here is the code below :

```
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(
    LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(
        "ar"
    )
)

Toast.makeText(this, R.string.language_changed_successfully, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```